# Unable to find bundled Java version in Flutter

Tags: java, flutter

[This is what happens when I run flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIqt5.png)

Hi everyone,

I'm a completely new 15 year old aspiring developer who's only started coding a few weeks ago. I'm really struggling to solve a problem I've run into. Whenever I run "Flutter doctor" in VScode I get the error

Android Studio (version 2022.2)
X Unable to find bundled Java version.

I've spent a few hours today going through documentation and trying to find solutions online but nothing seems to be working for me. I've tried updating paths in my "System Environment Variables"
I've tried adding "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\jdk-21.0.2" to my settings.json file. And nothing has worked so far.

If anyone is able to help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps on how to fix the issue based on your operating system:

Windows:

Go to the Android Studio installation directory (typically C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio).
Copy the contents of the jbr folder.
Paste the copied contents into the jre folder.
Run flutter doctor again to see if the issue is resolved.

OtherWise you can re-install android studio to fix this error.

Comment: I don't think I have the JRE folder, how do I fix that?

Comment: Follow this step to find JRE folder.
go to `c` drive -> program file || program file 86 -> android -> JRE folder.

If don't find JRE folder so re-install android studio in to first step.